# Pymongo, empty sorting

Tags: pymongo-3.x

How can I call pymongo sort() function with default empty arguments, so I would have no sorting.

```
collection.find(params).sort([])
ValueError: key_or_list must not be the empty list

collection.find(params).sort({})
TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

collection.find(params).sort([{}])
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

In mongo console I can do it with

```
db.collection.find().sort({})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not pass an empty list to sort.

below 2 queries return same results

```
self.collection.find()
self.collection.find().sort([("$natural", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

So if you want sort to be ignored just pass [("$natural", pymongo.ASCENDING)] to sort.

You can refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46897841/5068345)