# Is there a way to bind another function like limit() to pymongo query based on condition?

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a query which is as below:

```
def get_data(self, limit=None):
    # I just want to add limit() in case it is set, not otherwise
    self.collection.find(condition)
```

`self.collection` refers to the collection in the class. If `limit` parameter is **set** I need to bind `limit()` `pymongo` function to the query.

**NB:** the limit is just a sample case it could be any function like `sort`, etc. So I just want to know is there a mechanism to bind params like this?

Answer (score 2):

below 2 queries return same results

```
self.collection.find()
self.collection.find().sort([("$natural", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

[Sort Natural Order](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#return-in-natural-order)

and also below 2 queries return same results

```
self.collection.find()
self.collection.find().limit(0)
```

A limit of `0` is equivalent to no limit. [source](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#zero-value)

so you can combine these and write a single line query as follows

```
self.collection.find().limit(self.limit or 0).sort(self.sort or [("$natural", pymongo.ASCENDING)])
```

If you have set values for limit/sort they will be applied otherwise will be ignored.

Comment: u should be aware of index using while passing $natural: Index Use
Queries that include a sort by $natural order do not use indexes to fulfill the query predicate with the following exception: If the query predicate is an equality condition on the _id field { _id: <value> }, then the query with the sort by $natural order can use the _id index.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?:

```
def get_data(self, limit=None):
    cursor = self.collection.find(condition)
    if limit is not None:
        return cursor.limit(limit)
    else:
        return cursor
```

Comment: Yes, but now if you have to add another function like `sort` after `limit` what would it be like?